# Adding Canon Pixma MX870 Printer

Tags: 12.04, wireless, printing, canon

I've been trying to do some research on these forums to see how I can add my printer wirelessly. The first approach I found was with this thread http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1475336 but unfortunately when I follow the steps it gives me an error.

Second, I found a post that told me to add a PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository michael-gruz/canon
```

But all that does is raise a NoDistroTemplateException.

I'm not sure what that exception means, but I was just wondering if anyone else had these problems and how to succeed.

Answer (score 1):

I also had issues with installing this printer, but since 12.04 comes with the embedded driver that supports Canon PIXMA MX870, you shouldn't mess with other custom solutions in order to install this printer properly. Go to the router manager via your web browser and setup your printer's IP address as fixed.

1. Click "Dash Home" button
2. Type "Printing" and click at the icon
3. Add your Network printer here by using the dedicated IP address of your printer we've mentioned from above
4. Done.